# Using variables while inserting in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and trying to write a program in C# for insertion and deletion.
I want to know if there is a way i can use variables instead of values in the insert command ?
When i try the following:

```
string s1="A";
string s2="B";
session.Execute("insert into users (lastname, firstname) values (s1,s2)");
```

The error occurs: A first chance exception of type 'Cassandra.SyntaxError' occurred in Cassandra.dll

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are using the DataStax CQL3 C# Driver, the best way to go about this is to use a prepared statement.  Once you set that up, you bind your variables and `Execute`, like this:

```
string strCQL = "INSERT INTO users (lastname, firstname) VALUES (?,?)";
string s1 = "A";
string s2 = "B";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = session.Prepare(strCQL);
BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.Bind(s1,s2);
session.Execute(boundStatement);
```

Please don't ever build a CQL statement with string.Format (or string concatenation) and execute it.  Cassandra/CQL can also be subject to [injection-based attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), so you should always use a prepared statement and bind your variables to it.  Also, if you have a statement that you are going to run multiple times (ex: within a loop), you can get better performance by preparing it prior to the loop, and binding/executing within.

Answer (score 0):

You need String.format or better yet use prepared statements.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/csharp-driver/2.1/csharp-driver/reference/21features/namedParameters.html